# Программно изменить marginBottom кнопки android

Tags: java, android, android-button

Программно создаю кнопки, но недавно понадобилось делать отступ вниз от каждой кнопки. Я так понял надо задать **layout_marginbottom**.
Вот как создаю кнопку:

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonsLayout);
    Button b = new Button(linearLayout.getContext());
    b.setText(now_button.getString("name"));
        b.setLayoutParams(
           new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(                                                         
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                                                        
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
           )
        );                                        
    b.setTag(now_button.getString("buttonID"));
    b.setTextSize(12);
    linearLayout.addView(b);
```

Как мне программно задать layout_marginbottom? Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее  спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Вот как можно добавить отступы:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Вот общий вид как создавать программно кнопки и регулировать отступ:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

Button okButton=new Button(this);
okButton.setText("some text");
ll.addView(okButton, layoutParams);
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically) источник который даст вам дополнительную информацию касательно решения данного вопроса.